# Should I prefer uses or using here?

Tags: word-usage

my sentence is below:
As we’ve explained above that round bar(including both of metal and carbon material) has a helical cut on the surface that ***uses*** to determine the beauty value.

Should I utilize *uses* or *using* in this context?

Comment: Your sentence makes no sense to me at all. Can you add an explanation of what you mean to ask?

Comment: @DavoI there is a helical cut on the round bar, the helical cut is used to determine the beauty value of that round bar. I am trying to translate it from Chinese to English for practicing in English translation learning.

Comment: I don't understand what "beauty value" is - is this like "quality"? If so, Michael Harvey's answer below is good.

Comment: @Davo Yes, it is like "quality", thank you all the same^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. Possibly "As we’ve explained above, that round carbon and metal bar has a helical cut on the surface that ***is used*** to determine the beauty value."